# Evaluate a string as if it was connected by dot operator

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self, local_dict):
        self.local_dict = local_dict

    def acquire(self, foreign_dict, *args):
        to_exec = ''
        for arg in args:
            to_exec += ('.get(\'%s\', {})' %arg)
```

where calling `foo.acquire(some_dict, 'CLIENT1', 'OWED')` makes `to_exec` becomes something like:

```
.get('CLIENT1', {}).get('OWED', {})
```

which is meant to access an arbitrarily deeply nested dictionary `foreign_dict` while ensuring that a failed attempt does not block the program. My issue is, how do I run this string as if it was calling the method of a dict, i.e., how would I get something like this to be returned:

```
return foreign_dict.get('CLIENT1', {}).get('OWED', {})
```

if all I have is the string `'.get('CLIENT1', {}).get('OWED', {})'`?

In my code, all is fine and dandy if I do the following:

```
def acquire(self, *args):
    to_exec = 'self.local_dict'
    for arg in args:
        to_exec += ('.get(\'%s\', {})' %arg)
    return eval(to_exec)
```

But it works fine here because I know `self.local_dict`'s variable name and it isn't taken from the input. Is there any way to get the string to run as if it was connected with the dot operator to a foreign input, i.e. get it to run as  `return foreign_dict.get('CLIENT1', {}).get('OWED', {})`? Is there something like: `dot_operator(foreign_dict, eval(to_exec))`? Because `foreign_dict.eval(to_exec)` does not work.

Comment: See `getattr()`. There's no need for generating code as strings.

Comment: Which is to say, it's a bad idea to structure your program such that you have a string representing the things you want to look up at all. Much easier to have security bugs that way, in particular.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I thought it was clumsy too, but I didn't know how I could apply an object's method to itself a selected number of times. I will look up getattr(), thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strictly answer your answer with `eval`, what you want is possibly the `locals` parameter of `eval` (`eval` has 3 parameters):

```
     def acquire(self, foreign_dict, *args):
         to_exec = 'foreign_dict'
         for arg in args:
             to_exec += ('.get(\'%s\', {})' %arg)
         return eval(to_exec, globals(), {'foreign_dict': foreign_dict})
```

But in your case, you don't seem to actually need to use `eval`. You could just reassign a variable in a loop, and do `get` with it. Something like

```
temp = foreign_dict.get(args[0], {})
for arg in args[1:]:
    temp = temp.get(arg, {})
return temp
```